# brew services start mongodb-community@4.0 fails - uninitialized constant

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

I've followed the directions on the [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/) to install MongoDB on Mac using homebrew:

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew install mongodb-community@4.0
```

Then I can run it in the foreground using:

```
mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
```

But, when trying to start it as a service using:

```
brew services start mongodb-community@4.0
```

I get this error:

```
Error: mongodb-community: uninitialized constant #<Class:0x00007ff189061008>::Gem
```

I also get this error when running `brew doctor`:

```
Warning: Some installed formulae are not readable:
  mongodb-community: uninitialized constant #<Class:0x00007ffd903152a0>::Gem
```

Why this is happening? How do I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please check out whether it runs fine without running it as a mac os service

open the terminal and run the command mongod

Comment: Just updated the question. Yes I can run it in the foreground.

Comment: What is your specific version of MacOS? (one way to check from Terminal would be `sw_vers -productVersion`)

Comment: MacOS version: 10.14.4

Comment: Has anybody found a solution to this?, I am having the same issue and pulling my hair now for hours.

Comment: I've the same issue also

Comment: I have the same problem too

Comment: @SydAmir if it's interesting to register service as autostart so use launchctl as in my answer below. But for brew... need to wait when maintainers will solve issue.

Comment: Hey guys, quick update, a PR has been submitted on the repo and will be fixed soon. As a workaround you can follow this comment for now: https://github.com/mongodb/homebrew-brew/issues/6#issuecomment-491535727

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an error with the mongodb-community formula. [An issue has been filed](https://github.com/mongodb/homebrew-brew/issues/6) with the maintainers, [a solution found](https://github.com/mongodb/homebrew-brew/issues/6#issuecomment-491535727), and [a pull request with the fix](https://github.com/mongodb/homebrew-brew/pull/7) opened.

In the meantime, you can fix the error yourself. [This line](https://github.com/mongodb/homebrew-brew/blob/master/Formula/mongodb-community.rb#L13) in the formula is throwing an exception:

```
Gem::Version.new(v['version'])
```

because the Gem class has not been imported. Adding the import:

```
require 'rubygems'
```

solves the problem. You can do this locally, by finding and editing the formula on your computer. It is probably in this file:

```
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/mongodb/homebrew-brew/Formula/mongodb-community.rb
```

**Update:** A community contributor has fixed this upstream. If you are still experiencing this issue you might need to run brew update

Comment: Nice research, Thank You (:

Answer (score 4):

I know it's not correct answer since we are talking about registering service using:

```
brew services start mongodb-community
```

But I've **SOLVED** service registration question this way:

```
sudo cp /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/4.0.9/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist /Library/LaunchAgents/

launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist

launchctl start mongodb-community
```